# Create custom entities as in Dynamics 365 in C#

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to create a solution that deploys (creates) set of custom entities. how can i do this? would i use plugins? what would be the activation event?

I want to create a c# solution package that i can deploy to any Dynamics 365 that creates custom entities.

any help is appreciate it on this.

Comment: Do you mean entities (e.g. contact) or records (e.g. James Wood)?

Comment: Maybe CreateEntityRequest is the thing you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/create-custom-entity

Answer (score 0):

You can create the entities in your dev environment then export them as part of an unmanaged or managed solution.
One way to do it would be to create the solution first, then create the entity from within the solution.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/introduction-solutions) more on solutions.

Comment: the question above is how to do this in c# solution and not through the import and export xml files that are generated from D365.

Comment: If you're going to deploy a C# solution to create the entities, why not put the entities themselves into the solution?

Comment: This is my question: how can i setup a solution to create these entities? since custom entities is one thing in the solution but i can do other tasks related to the app i am building. if you have a sample on how to do this it would be great. I saw the sample in the SDK but it didn't provide end to end solution. it has bunch of code that does unrelated tasks but not designed to tackle custom entities creation as one step in the solution deployment.

Comment: If you want to do other things when you import the solution you might want to look at the tool called [Package Deployer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-packages-package-deployer).